# Copy worksheet from one Workbook to another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to copy a worksheet name "Headings Explanations" from the current workbook "Create Report.xlsm"  that is open to a work book that i have asked to be opened 
I get subscript out of range error

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim myfile As String

myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose a file to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile

Workbooks("Create Report.xlsm").Sheets("Headings Explanations").Copy After:=Workbooks(myfile).Sheets(Sheet.Count)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*myfile* is the full drive, folder path and filename. To reference an open workbook in the Workbooks collection, you only want the filename. Set a workbook var to the opened workbook and use that instead.

Sheet.count was singlular; should be workSheets.count or sheets.count.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim myfile As String, wbo as workbook

    myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose a file to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

    set wbo = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myfile)

    Workbooks("Create Report.xlsm").workSheets("Headings Explanations").Copy After:=wbo.workSheets(workSheets.Count)

End Sub
```